# will_paginate gem using model associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I am using the will_paginate gem and I am attempting to utilize it using model associations. Right now, I have Group and Post models, where each group has a list of posts. However, when I attempt to chain these models using will_paginate, it does not work. Yet I test this in my terminal with `Group.find(15).posts.order('created_at DESC')` and it works. Not sure if I am missing something or if it has to do with how I'm handling the partials.

Group show.html.erb

```
<%= render "posts/index" %>
```

Post _index.html.erb

```
<%= render 'posts/posts' %>
...
<%= will_paginate @posts %>
```

Post _posts.html.erb

```
<% @group.posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= render 'posts/post', post: post, group: @group %>
<% end %>
```

Post _post.html.erb

```
...
<%= post.caption %>
```

Post index.js.erb

```
$('#posts').append("<%= escape_javascript(render 'posts')%>");
$('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= escape_javascript will_paginate(@posts) %>');
```

scroll.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if ($('.pagination').length) {
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href');
  if (url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50) {
    $('.pagination').text("Please Wait...");
    return $.getScript(url);
  }
 });
 return $(window).scroll();
}
});
```

Group controller

```
def show
    @group = Group.find(params[:id])
    @posts = @group.posts.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 3).order('created_at DESC')
end
```

I also tried `@posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 3).order('created_at DESC')` but it doesn't seem to work. My list of posts are not ordered in descending order nor are grouped in threes. Any advice on how to utilize this gem when using multiple models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is that you are settings up `@posts` correctly, but then instead of using it you iterate over `@group.posts`, here in the views:

```
# posts/_index.html.erb
<%= render 'posts/posts' %>
...
<%= will_paginate @posts %>

# posts/_posts.html.erb 
<% @group.posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= render 'posts/post', post: post, group: @group %>
<% end %>
```

Instead do this:

```
# posts/_posts.html.erb 
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= render 'posts/post', post: post, group: @group %>
<% end %>
```

Note that the `<%= will_paginate @posts %>` part **only** draws the navigation controls. The list of posts is coming from the `render posts/posts`.

Comment: Awesome! That did the trick. Now I am having issues getting my continuous scrolling feature to work via the index.js.erb and scroll.js files I have. I had these features working but am in the process of abstracting everything into groups thus using model associations.

Comment: I don't think I can help with continuous scrolling, but if you write a new question for it I'm sure there are people who can!

Comment: Thanks! I'll try tackling it for a while and see if I can figure it out. Thanks for your help as well as to ollaollu for the suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

according to the docs on the gem, the paginate call should be `paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)` and not `paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 3)` like you used in your code.

That is where your problem may lie. If that doesn't fix it, you can also try:

```
def show
  @group = Group.find(params[:id])
  @posts = @group.posts.order('created_at DESC').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 3)
end
```

One thing I do when I use pagination in my applications is to paginate only after I am done getting the results of my query.

Comment: Still no luck. I am confused as to why this isn't working as it should and it does in my terminal when doing `Group.find(15).posts.order('created_at DESC')` for example

Comment: can I see your view code? where you iterate over `@posts`

Comment: I updated my original post above adding in more code. Please let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: @ollaollu FYI "paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)" is exactly the same than "paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)"